# Twilio Notify toBindings

Tags: node.js, twilio

I have multiple bindings to an identity, let's say APN and SMS.
If I read and what I understand is that you can specify what type of binding you want to sent it to via the "**toBinding**" attribute? But I'm getting an error if I use that attribute...

```
const notificationOpts = {
  identity: '45A4B6D0-BBA8-4C9E-B0B8-DCA1433C1E65',
  toBinding: ['sms'],
  body: 'Knok-Knok! This is your first Notify SMS',
};

client.notify
  .services('ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
  .notifications.create(notificationOpts)
  .then(notification => console.log(notification))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

The ERROR message I get when I use the code above.

```
{ [Error: Can not convert incoming parameters to Notification object: Parameter 'ToBinding' is invalid]
  status: 400,
  message: 'Can not convert incoming parameters to Notification object: Parameter \'ToBinding\' is invalid',
  code: 20001,
  moreInfo: 'https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20001',
  detail: undefined }
```

Comment: The example here looks different then your code snippet, https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/notification-resource (Send a Notification to Bindings in the request).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The `toBinding` attribute is actually for sending notifications to users that you haven't previously created bindings for. To [select the correct channel to send the notification you should use the `Tag` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/notification-resource?code-sample=code-send-custom-notifications-by-channel&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=6.x#send-a-notification-tailored-to-the-specific-channel).

As the documentation says:

> #### Tag
>
> A tag that selects the Bindings to notify. Repeat this parameter to specify more than one tag, up to a total of 5 tags. The implicit tag all is available to notify all Bindings in a Service instance. Similarly, **the implicit tags apn, fcm, gcm, sms and facebook-messenger are available to notify all Bindings in a specific channel**.

So, you should use the following `notificationOpts` in your original example:

```js
const notificationOpts = {
  identity: '45A4B6D0-BBA8-4C9E-B0B8-DCA1433C1E65',
  tag: ['sms'],
  body: 'Knok-Knok! This is your first Notify SMS',
};
```

Let me know if that helps.